# bonding configuration when SLAVE=yes

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

In my network configuration I see the settings of `SLAVE=yes`

what is mean that - `SLAVE=yes`

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=none 
ONBOOT=yes 
# Settings for Bond 
MASTER=bond0 
SLAVE=yes
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
DEVICE=eth1 
BOOTPROTO=none  
ONBOOT=yes 
USERCTL=no 
# Settings for bonding 
MASTER=bond0 
SLAVE=yes
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2
DEVICE=eth2 
BOOTPROTO=none 
ONBOOT=yes 
MASTER=bond0 
SLAVE=yes
```

and in case both interfaces are slave , in the configuration seems to be as load balancing, then what is the procedure to test this configuration ?

I mean how to do real test on the bond that both ETH react as load balance ?

Comment: you can check their incoming and out-coming network

Comment: not clearly remark =- can you post your answer